# Python setuptools/pip packing data files into your package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have this git repo structure:

```
.gitignore
JSONs/subdirA/some.json
JSONs/subdirB/other.json
MyPackage/__init__.py
MyPackage/myModule.py
```

How do I properly pack the `JSONs` folder into `MyPackage/JSONs`, without moving it there permanently (mostly because customers use this git repo directly for non-python usage, and the folder at the top of the repo is easy/intuitive... But now I also want to release this same dir into my PyPi package)?

I've tried adding it to the `MANIFEST.in` and then playing with `data_files` in `setup.py` as well as `package_data`... But to no avail. Maybe some .pyc or cached build files got the best of me... But I haven't figured it out from all the other (not quite) duplicate questions as they don't specifically call out their directory structure and desired final location.

I've tried resorting to `os.walk` and `shutil.copy` before the call to `setup` and then deleting that directory after `setup`... While it seems to work locally, when pushing to our local devpi package server, something goes wrong. Is my goal totally off the radar for setuptools/pip ideals??? Or am I just missing some key understanding? Please enlighten me!

Comment: Why not simply using symlinks to make it look like this `JSONs` directory is inside `MyPackage`? Then the rest is pretty standard ([here for example](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html)). Do not use `data_files`, use `MANIFEST.in` and `package_data`.

Comment: can symlinks be committed to GIT though? In a cross-platform way (The python package works on Windows primarily, but the C code that uses the JSONs works on linux)

Comment: I guess it does. But otherwise you can use _setuptools_'s `package_dir` to rewrite the path to the `JSONs` directory. Something like `package_dir = {'MyPackage.JSONs': 'JSONs'}`, assuming your `setup.py` is in the same directory as `.gitignore` (the root directory). -- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages

Comment: Thanks, I'll give `package_dir` a try now. The confusing thing about the page you linked earlier is, the data files are inside the package already, while in my case they're not. So my earlier attempts were leaving the `JSONs` folder in either `sys.prefix` or `site-packages` depending on what I was trying.

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point of `package_dir`, it will transform `./JSONs` into `MyPackage/JSONs`, when it does the build, i.e. in the _wheel_ it has the new path, but in the _sdist_ it still has the old structure.

Comment: With `package_dir`, a very strange situation now.... when I run `devpi upload` my package makes to to PyPi and the tests run (including one to check the JSONs are present) and everything passes. However if I run `pip install .` or `python setup.py install` locally I don't see the `JSONs` folder anywhere in `C:\Python37`. Downloading the `ZIP` file from PyPi's "dev" release area, I see the `JSONs` dir outside of my package... but if I install it `pip install MyPackage.zip` I still don't get the `JSONs` anywhere in `C:\Python37`. Super confused as to why it works remotely and not locally.

Comment: hrmm, ok seems like something locally is very strange. The `pip install MyPackage.zip` created a `.whl` file, which I am trying to install, but it fails saying my package is already installed. `pip uninstall MyPackage` worked once, but `pip install` still fails saying it's already satisfied. I manually deleted a `.pth` file, but still not installing. I've tried researching this issue before with no luck as it's intermittent, not sure where it's stemming from... maybe the occasional use of `pip install -e .`

Comment: ok, it was a bunch of variously named `.EGG` files... the wheel itself lacks the `JSONs` folder at any level though.

Comment: I have something that works, but it's a bit hackish. Would be better if there were some `__init__.py` files at least in `JSONs` (and probably in the subdrectories as well). So 2 questions: **1.** Is the complete list of directories in `JSONs` known in advance and relatively small? **2.** Can we add some `__init__.py` files in `JSONs`?

Comment: There are 30 sub-dirs in `JSONs`, it would be a little "noisy" to have `__init__.py` in each, but not a deal breaker. The worst case would be if some less-involved contributors added a new dir there, but didn't add the `__init__.py`, and I forgot to check during release of the PyPi package... resulting in a failure to deploy all the `JSONs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following could help:

First we need to make sure that the *json* files are added to the *source distribution*.

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include JSONs *.json
```

Then in the actual *setup* script, the list of *packages* has to be modified on the fly to take into account the target package structure.

`setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

PACKAGES = (
    setuptools.find_packages(exclude=['JSONs*'])
    +
    [
        f'MyPackage.{package}'
        for package
        in setuptools.find_namespace_packages(include=['JSONs*'])
    ]
)

setuptools.setup(
    packages=PACKAGES,
    package_dir={
        'MyPackage.JSONs': 'JSONs',
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    #
    name='Something',
    version='1.2.3',
)
```

`JSONs/subdirA/some.json` :

```
{"Marco": "Polo"}
```

Such *package data* can be read like so:

`MyPackage/myModule.py`:

```
import pkgutil

print(pkgutil.get_data('MyPackage', 'JSONs/subdirA/some.json').decode())
```

And use it like in the following:

```
$ python -m pip install .
$ # Move to another directory to prevent that the current working directory
$ # ... overshadows the installed project
$ cd ..
$ python -m MyPackage.myModule
{"Marco": "Polo"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, without adding any `__init__.py` files

Comment: I'm glad it helps solve your issues. Indeed, we didn't need to add `__init__.py` files, it kind of surprised me, but whatever... I don't really like that we had to set `include_package_data = True` though, but -again- whatever... It works.